# Problem with template type T not being understood by my operator overloading friend function

Tags: c++

This is a continuation of my last post. I'm getting this error now:

```
Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T'
```

This is happening because of a friend operator overload function not understanding the type T being overloaded for some reason.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class LL
{
    struct Node
    {
        T mData;
        Node *mNext;

        Node();
        Node(T data);
    };

private:
    Node *mHead, *mTail;
    int mCount;

public:
    LL();
    ~LL();
    bool insert(T data);
    bool isExist(T data);
    bool remove(T data);
    void showLinkedList();
    void clear();
    int getCount() const;
    bool isEmpty();

    friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& output, const LL& obj)
    {
        Node* tmp;

        if (obj.mHead != NULL)
        {
            tmp = obj.mHead;

            while (tmp != NULL)
            {
                output << tmp->mData << std::endl; // "tmp->mData" is where the error is
                tmp = tmp->mNext;
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

};
```

Comment: What is `T`? Does it have a `operator<<` for ofstreams?

Comment: I find working with Stream I/O is easiest if you make a public `void print(std::ostream&) const;` method, and have the `std::ostream& operator>>(std::ostream& o, Foo const& foo) { foo.print(o); return o; }` to avoid exposing your privates to your friends.

Comment: [Exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55652315/3233393).

Answer (score 0):

Your stream operator should be defined with `std::ostream` not `std::ofstream`, e.g.:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const LL& obj)
```